# how to prevent scientific notation with Float in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code :

```
rangeSlider.minLabel?.text = "\(rangeSlider.lowerValue)"
```

The label text is **1e+07** but I want to be 100000000.

How should I disable scientific notation ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Format your number style :

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
let finalNumber = numberFormatter.number(from: "\(rangeSlider.lowerValue)")
print(finalNumber!)
```

---

With the conversion of simple 1e+07

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
let finalNumber = numberFormatter.number(from: "\(1e+07)")
print(finalNumber!)
```

Output :

> 10000000

Hope this helps.

Comment: For future readers, it's now `NumberFormatter` and a `numberStyle` of `.decimal`. And, obviously, if you're converting a number to a string like the OP asked, you'd use [`string(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/numberformatter/1408845-number).

Answer (score 8):

Another approach is to use `String(format:)` which is available if you have `Foundation` imported:

Example:

```
import Foundation  // this comes with import UIKit or import Cocoa

let f: Float = 1e+07
let str = String(format: "%.0f", f)
print(str)  // 10000000
```

In your case:

```
rangeSlider.minLabel?.text = String(format: "%.0f", rangeSlider.lowerValue)
```

Comment: This worked for me with negative scientific notation whereas the above from Ashish did not.

Comment: This solution also works for me, both numbers larger and smaller than 1. The solution by Ashish only works for numbers larger than 1.

Comment: Didn't work for smaller than 1 in xcode 12/swift4

Answer (score 6):

### Solution w/ extension (Swift 4+, Xcode 9)

I've just had the same problem to face. For displaying this kind of numbers in a string, I've created the following extension:

```
extension Double {

    func toString(decimal: Int = 9) -> String {
        let value = decimal < 0 ? 0 : decimal
        var string = String(format: "%.\(value)f", self)

        while string.last == "0" || string.last == "." {
            if string.last == "." { string = String(string.dropLast()); break}
            string = String(string.dropLast())
        }
        return string
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var scientificNumber: Double = 1e+06
print(scientificNumber.toString())  // 1000000

scientificNumber = 1e-06
print(scientificNumber.toString())  // 0.000001

scientificNumber = 1e-14
print(scientificNumber.toString())  // 0 (too small for the default tollerance.)
print(scientificNumber.toString(decimal: 15)) // 0.00000000000001
```

For floats works as well. Just extend Float instead of Double.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4.2**

Disable scientific notation:

```
let number = NSNumber(value: rangeSlider.lowerValue)
print(number.decimalValue)

rangeSlider.minLabel?.text = "\(number.decimalValue)"
```

Comment: It works well for me with both larger and smaller than 1. I am using xcode 12/swift4