# Converting Int64 to Float in Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift

Please let me know what I am doing wrong in below statements, its not compiling (where I have casted the Int64 to Float)

```
 func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse) {
    NSLog("data came")
    var expectedDownloadSize:Float = (Float) response.expectedContentLength

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are getting confused between Obj-C and Swift in a couple of places. As Robert says you need to place the value you want to case within parenthesis wrapped around the type, eg: `Float(response.expectedContentLength).` It is also worth noting that `NSLog` has been deprecated in Swift in favour of `print(...)`. Additionally, you no longer need to explicitly declare the variable type as Swift will pick this up automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Casting in Swift is done slightly differently:

```
var expectedDownloadSize = Float(response.expectedContentLength)
```

Rather than casting to a value, you actually use `Float`'s initialiser, which takes an `Int64` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

in swift you can do like this:

var expectedDownloadSize:Float = Float (response.expectedContentLength)

try

Comment: This answer is an exact duplicate of an existing one, I suggest you delete it.

Comment: Hi All,

Actually After I posted the question I got the error and resolved the issue but int64 number is not converted to float...:(

Comment: I am getting 1.34597e+08 in float but I don't want to have this scientific notation. How can i convert?

Comment: you can check this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022438/how-to-prevent-scientific-notation-with-float-in-swift