# display as a number instead of exponential number

Tags: ios, swift2, numbers, exponential

I have a slider in my app. I am using the value of slider to calculate another value in my code. Here is the code.

```
    let P = slider1.value
    let mulValue = 1.00
    let i = P * mulValue
    print("i:", i)
```

Slider min value = 0 , Slider Max value = 9,999,999. If the slider value is more than 1,000,000 the value of i is displayed as exponential number.

For example, value of "i" printed: 1.55058e+06 in console for P = 1,550,580
I want the full number to be printed instead of exponential number. How do I correct this issue?

As per the comments below, I tried using NSNumberFormatter(). But there resulted number is rounded. I do not want my "i" to be rounded. Below is code snippet I used, Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks !!

```
    let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
    let finalNumber = numberFormatter.numberFromString(String(i))
    print("fin num:", finalNumber)
```

Comment: Update your question with how you display the value `i`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to prevent scientific notation with Float in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022438/how-to-prevent-scientific-notation-with-float-in-swift)

Comment: The solution in the above link is not working in my case. The number is rounded off. When P = 6,401,326, my i = Optional(6401330).

Comment: @rmaddy `print("i:", i)`

Comment: That's a comment, not an update to your question. It's a print statement. Don't worry about it much. But if you really want a specific format, use a `NumberFormatter` setup as desired.

Comment: If you are having issues with using `NumberFormatter`, then [edit] your question with relevant code.

Comment: `print(String(format: "i: %.0f", i))`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your inputs. 
There is slight different in the usage of `NSNumberFormatter()`
The following code worked for my code perfectly.

```
    let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
    let finalNumber = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(i)!
    print("fin:", finalNumber)
```

I used `stringFromNumber` instead of `numberFromString`